# Difference between noarch rpm and a rpm

Tags: linux, centos, operating-system, redhat, rpm

Can someone explain difference between noarch rpm and rpm. Is these two are dependents. I have Jenkins rpm and there are some noarch rpm  too. what I can do with noarch rpm. Thanks for your help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

if the rpm is called `*.noarch.rpm` that **should** mean that this rpm can be installed on any architecture. The contents (files) installed by that rpm are bash script, text files, documentation, or any other kind of files that don't depend on the architecture; so **never** compiled binaries.

Note however that it is the **packager** who decides that his rpm will be a **noarch**. If he makes a bad decision; he *can* create a noarch rpm containing compiled binaries.